# Windows Server 2012 R2 shows blank blue screen with cursor moving on it

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have recently updated my windows server 2012 R2 and after restarting it just shows me blank screen with mouse cursor, it does not shows any login screen.
And even if i try login remotely it just ask for credentials and then shows nothing.
But i can access my shared folders and all. Only i cannot is login and see my desktop.

I even tried to restore to last known good configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it ask for credentials at all locally?

I know it isn't much help, but, it obviously seems like something is broken with Windows Login (locally) or Explorer (remotely).

If this was me, I would continue on remotely and try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, and then open task manager and manually run explorer, or try the same via sysinternals psexec.

Also, try safe mode and running `sfc /scannow`.

If this is on a domain, try also using Event Viewer and connecting remotely - it is very helpful in situations like this.

Unfortunately with the information you have given, I'm not sure there is much more I can advise.

Comment: Even after going to SAFE MODE and SAFE Mode with cmd it brings the same screen

Answer (score 0):

It may be a corrupted profile.

- Try to start a task manager (Shift+Ctrl+Esc) and launch an explorer.exe instance from there.

If that does not work...

- Just wait. It can be quite a while, but after a few minutes it may load correctly. After that, create a new profile and delete the old one.
- Alternatively, try to login via RDP (with /admin level session).
- A restart with low resolution may also be a bypass of the problem if it's something video adapter-related.

Comment: i tried  Shift+Ctrl+Esc, And even i tried doing remotely but it just ask for credentials and then it display nothing

Comment: If you get to input credentials it's definitely a corrupted profile. Try a login with a different profile.

Comment: i tried but its the same ...